# "Class not found" What did I miss?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to add Accessors and Mutators to a model. In Laravel 4 it worked all fine, but with Laravel 5 I have some trouble.
I have a "lib" folder in my App directory which contains the "db_transformers.php" file. This file holds classes like "dbDate" with a set and get function to transform dates stored in the database to a user-friendly format.

The "db_transformers.php" file is namespaced:

```
<?php namespace App\lib;
```

I also rerfer to the folder in my model:

```
use App\lib;
```

But  my methodes still throw errors:

```
public function getDateTimeAttribute($value)
{
    return dbDate::get($value);
}
```

This will return a "Class 'App\dbDate' not found" error.

What could be my problem?

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: Doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing autoloading (PHP including/requiring a class definition file) with namespaces (a system that allows hierarchical naming of PHP classes/functions to help prevent code conflicts).

It's an easy thing to do.  Covering the changes to autoloading in Laravel 5 is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question, but if you're interested I've written a multiple article series on [how autoloading works with composer/Laravel 4/Laravel 5](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#autoloading).

To your specific question, you say you've defined a class named `dbDate` in a file named `db_transformers.php`, and `db_transformers.php` has a namespace of `App\lib`.

```
#File: lib/db_transformers.php
namespace App\lib;
//other code
class dbDate
{
    //other code
}
//other code
```

This mean your class's full name is `App\lib\dbDate`.  The **entire thing** is the class's name.  That's probably the biggest thing to get used to with namespaces in PHP.

This means if you wanted to use the class in other code, you'd need to refer to the full class name, including a leading backslash.

```
return \App\lib\DbDate::get($value);
```

You could also import the class using the `use` keyword

```
use App\lib\DbDate;
//other code
public function getDateTimeAttribute($value)
{
    //since we imported the class with `use`, we don't need to type the full name
    return DbDate::get($value);
}
```

The use keywords *imports* a specific class into the current namespace.  When you said

```
use App\lib;
```

you were telling PHP

> You know that global class`App\lib`?  I'm going to refer to it below as `lib`

Since you don't have a class named `lib`, this is meaningless, and it's why your `use` didn't help.

So that's namespaces.  The other problem you need to solve is autoloading.  Autoloading is what lets you skip the  `require` or `include` statement/function when you want a class definition files in your project.

Laravel 4 used a bunch of different autoloaders, including something called a `classmap` autoloader.  The classmap autoloader automatically parses all the files in your project looking for classes, and creates a giant map of which class is where (that's over simplifying it a bit, see the [article series](http://alanstorm.com/category/laravel#autoloading) I linked earlier for the full details).

In Laravel 4, the `classmap` autoloader probably read the file in `lib` for you.  [Laravel 5 reduced the number of autoloaders](http://alanstorm.com/laravel_5_autoloader), which included getting rid of the classmap autoloader for most folders.

The simplest thing you can do in Laravel 5 is to configure your project to use the classmap autoloader again.  Open up `composer.json` and find this section

```
    "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                    "database"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                    "App\\": "app/"
            }
    },
```

And add `lib` to the `classmap` autoloader section

```
    "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                    "database",
                    "lib"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                    "App\\": "app/"
            }
    },
```

This tells composer to include the `lib` folders when it creates its autoloader files.  You'll need to run the `dumpautoload` command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

after doing that, and you should be able to use the classes defined in `lib/db_transformers.php` as you wish.

Comment: Thanks you, great explanation :) I learned a lot from your answer!
Just one point, I added "app/lib" and not "app" to the classmap ;)

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the complete class name: `use App\lib\dbDate;`

You might also look into using view decorators for this purpose, as doing it in your model is really not appropriate.

Several packages exist to help with this, e.g. https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter